# XPATH for Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

So i am using SCRAPY to scrape off the books of a website.

I have the crawler working and it crawls fine, but when it comes to cleaning the HTML using the select in XPATH it is kinda not working out right. Now since it is a book website, i have almost 131 books on each page and their XPATH comes to be likes this

For example getting the title of the books -

```
1st Book --- > /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/a/span
2nd Book --->  /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span 
3rd book --->  /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span
```

The DIV[] number increases with the book. I am not sure how to get this into a loop, so that it catches all the titles. I have to do  this for Images and Author names too, but i think it will be similar. Just need to get this initial one done.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The `li` number increases, not the `div` one. Are you sure there is `img` at the end of the first expression and not `span`?

Comment: also div[2] should be div[position()=2] . could you try perhaps not to use absolute path, but grab titles or any elements by some id/class or any other attribute?

Comment: The thing, is i have to use absolute path because most of them would have same ID/Class name. @Choroba, sorry that was a typo, that is a /span.

Comment: For example while getting price all the classes are like this - "class="fksd-bodytext price final-price" so if i grab this class, i get everything on the page.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to get this

1. Best to select multiple nodes is, selecting on the basis of ids or class.
   e.g:

   ```
   sel.xpath("//div[@id='id']")
   ```
2. You can select like this

   ```
   for i in range(0, upto_num_of_divs):
       list = sel.xpath("//div[%s]" %i)
   ```
3. You can select like this

   ```
   for i in range(0, upto_num_of_divs):
       list = sel.xpath("//div[position > =1 and position() < upto_num_of_divs])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can parse your example html:

```
lis = hxs.select('//div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li')
for li in lis:
    book_el = li.select('a/span/text()')
```

Often enough you can do something like `//div[@class="final-price"]//span` to get the list of all the spans in one xpath. The exact expression depends on your html, this is just to give you an idea.

Otherwise the code above should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did find a chrome extention "XPATH VIEWER", it just gives me the XPATH by right click on the element i want. For example it will give me an output like this =  //*[@id="search_results"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h2/a/text()