# Using Scrapy to get text from a DIV element

Tags: python, scrapy

By using Scrapy package how can I get the product name from tatacliq.com when it has multiple  elements

HTML is like follow:
[image]

Comment: This is far too broad and vague. Stack Overflow is not the place to dump your work off for others to do. Also, please don’t use images to share code or data.

Answer (score 0):

The `Div` should have a unique identifier such as `id` or a `class name` to select the inner Text or Html inside the `Div`
If none of them exists you can even relay on the hierarchical position of the `Div` in the HTML document,

1. Best to select multiple nodes is, selecting on the basis of ids or class.
   e.g:

   ```
   sel.xpath("//div[@id='id']")
   ```
2. You can select like this

   ```
   position = i
   DIV = sel.xpath("//div[%s]" %i)
   ```

Source : [XPATH for Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500624/xpath-for-scrapy)